# Javascript localStorage not reciving input from form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on saving data from a HTML form to localStorage.

Here is my code so far

HTML

```
<form onSubmit="newRecipe()">
  Recipe Name:<br>
  <input type="text" value="Recipe" name="Recipe"><br>
  Ingredients:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Ingredients" value="Ingredients"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
function newRecipe(){
     var inputrecipe= document.getElementById("Recipe");
     localStorage.setItem("Recipe", JSON.stringify(Recipe));

  var inputingredients= document.getElementById("Ingredients");
  localStorage.setItem("Ingredients", inputingredients.value, JSON.stringify(testObject));
    }
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("Recipe");
```

What am I doing wrong? when I submit the form I get a white screen and no localStorage save

Comment: You need to have the `newRecipe()` function return false to prevent it from trying to POST to a blank page.

Comment: how would I go about that?

Comment: Literally add `return false;` as the last statement in the function...

Comment: Comment: Always try/catch localStorage usage. See http://crocodillon.com/blog/always-catch-localstorage-security-and-quota-exceeded-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code.You don't have elements with ID `Recipe` and `Ingredients`

Modify HTML like this

```
<form id="form">
  Recipe Name:<br>
  <input type="text" value="Recipe" name="Recipe" id="Recipe"><br>
  Ingredients:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Ingredients" value="Ingredients" id="Ingredients"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JS

1)When you submit the form, you need to trigger a function.

```
var form=document.getElementById("form");
form.onsubmit=function(){
   //code here
}
```

2)To get the value of input use `.value` property,like this:

`var inputrecipe= document.getElementById("Recipe").value;`

3) Include line `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("Recipe");` inside function.

```
var form=document.getElementById("form");
form.onsubmit=function(){
   alert("it is hitting");
   var inputrecipe= document.getElementById("Recipe").value;
   localStorage.setItem("Recipe", JSON.stringify(inputrecipe));

   var inputingredients= document.getElementById("Ingredients").value;
   localStorage.setItem("Ingredients",JSON.stringify(inputingredients));
   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("Recipe");
   return false;
}
```

Here is a working [solution](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyyrMY)

Comment: still nothing when I submit the form

Comment: As  @War10ck said, did you try to add `return false;` as the last statement in the function called `newRecipe()`?

Comment: I did, I am still getting a null error when trying to retrieve the data

Comment: It is hitting `newRecipe()` function ?

Comment: Yes, but I am unsure if it is saving the form data

Comment: @Top-Bot, Please post how look `test` element

Comment: It posts the word null

Comment: Thanks! You are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in your code. For one you don't actually assign an `id` to the elements you try to get. I changed your code up slightly and used jQuery (just because it is faster typing it and less code to write). I also suggest following normal naming conventions like giving your variables lower case names (unless they are constructors) and camelCasing. In HTML you might want to try to keep everything to lower case and use `-` instead.

This does NOT yet read from localStorage and doesn't display the values in the fields. But it does save it. I hope you can figure out the rest from here with the bread crumbs. :)

HTML:

```
<form id='form'>
  Recipe Name:<br>
  <input type="text" value="Recipe" name="recipe" id="recipe">
  <br>
  Ingredients:<br>
  <input type="text" name="ingredients" value="ingredients" id="ingredients">
  <br><br>
</form> 
<button>Submit</button>
```

JS:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var name = $('#recipe').val();
  var ingredients = $('#ingredients').val();
  localStorage.setItem(name, ingredients);  
});
```